# Delphi Getting Stream read error on really simple program

Tags: delphi, stream

I am experiencing a strange error which I have narrowed down to a small piece of code (see below). I am reading a binary file into a TMemoryStream (variable ms1), through a TFileStream object (variable fs). Then I want to copy the binary data to another TMemoryStream object (ms2). This is what gives me the "stream read error" exception. Strange thing is, that if I don't load up the ms1 object with the file contents, things work fine, i.e. ms2.CopyFrom does not give me an exception..

Any help is greatly appreciated....

```
procedure TForm5.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ms1: TMemoryStream;
  fs: TFileStream;
  ms2 : TMemoryStream;
  FilePath: string;
begin
  FilePath := 'C:\weekcpdf_tech6.bin';

  ms1 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  fs := nil;
  try
    ms1 := TMemoryStream.Create;
    fs := TFileStream.Create(FilePath, fmOpenRead);

    ms1.CopyFrom(fs, fs.Size);

    ms2 := TMemoryStream.Create;
    ms2.CopyFrom(ms1, ms1.Size);

  finally
    FreeAndNil(fs);
    FreeAndNil(ms1);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

First, you have a memory leak, since you create two memory stream objects that you assign to `ms1`. Remove the second one.

Second, after `ms1.CopyFrom(fs, fs.Size);` you must set `ms1.Position := 0` so that you copy from the start of `ms1` -- and not from the end of it.

This is actually fairly well [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStream.CopyFrom):

> CopyFrom copies Count bytes from the stream specified by Source into the stream. It then moves the current position by Count bytes and returns the number of bytes copied.

Hence, after `ms1.CopyFrom(fs, fs.Size);` you are at the end of `ms1`. Further,

> If Count is greater than or less than 0, CopyFrom reads from the current position in Source.

Therefore, `ms2.CopyFrom(ms1, ms1.Size);` will read from the current position (= the end!) of `ms1`. Hence, you will likely try to read a lot of bytes that do not exist. And what happens then?

> Because the CopyFrom method uses ReadBuffer and WriteBuffer to do the effective copying, if the Count is greater than the SourceStream size, ReadBuffer throws an exception stating that a stream read error has occured [sic!].

Always read the docs! :)

(Although I must admit that the last quote isn't quite perfect in this situation.)

Comment: or use ms2.CopyFrom(ms1, 0) to copy complete stream

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: True.